# Get raw message instead of String in WebSocket JSR 356

Tags: java, parsing, websocket, jetty

Right now the `MessageHandler.Whole<byte[]>` only activates when the message is actually just bytes.

**Will only activate when bytes arrive**

```
@Override
public void onMessage(byte[] message) { ... }
```

Is it possible to get the raw message (the WebSocket should not check wether it is a string or not) even though it is actually text data? The reason for that is because it would give some performance benefit when parsing raw bytes instead of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature you provided ...

```
public void onMessage(byte[] message)
```

Is for WebSocket messages sent as BINARY, not TEXT.

Per the various specs (both the protocol spec: RFC6455, and the javax.websocket spec: JSR-356), a TEXT message has a mandatory UTF8 validation requirement.

If you want to send Strings without this UTF8 validation requirement, then send them as BINARY WebSocket Messages instead.